# Selecting HTML radio buttons using jQuery.eq()

Tags: jquery, html, radio-button

I have 3 pairs of radio buttons named "gender[]" in my form. I want to check the first value of each pair using jQuery. I was thinking that this would do the trick:

```
jQuery('[name="gender\\[\\]"]:eq(1)').attr('checked', 'checked');
jQuery('[name="gender\\[\\]"]:eq(2)').attr('checked', 'checked');
jQuery('[name="gender\\[\\]"]:eq(3)').attr('checked', 'checked');
```

Instead, this code only checks the second value of the second pair (?). If I do:

```
jQuery('[name="gender\\[\\]"]:eq(1)').attr('checked', 'checked');
```

The second value of the first pair is check, which is normal. But then if I have one line of code like this:

```
jQuery('[name="gender\\[\\]"]:eq(1)').attr('checked', 'checked');
jQuery('[name="gender\\[\\]"]:eq(2)').attr('checked', 'checked');
```

The first value of the second pair is checked. But the first pair is entirely unchecked, as if the second line of code "cancelled" the first one.

What on earth is going on and how to check the first value of each pair?

Comment: Each radio group can only have one checked input.

Comment: You can only check one radio button out of all, that's what radio buttons are for. You can use checkbox if you want to check all

Comment: Each of these radio button pairs corresponds to a group member in a registration form. I'm trying to check only one value per group, not several. And since I use brackets, each gender[] is, or at least logically should be, a separate group.

Comment: `:eq()` is zero based, so in your example, should you be checking `eq(0)`, `eq(2)` and `eq(4)`?

Answer (score 1):

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j7wgm/)

Please check the Fiddle above.
As far i understood, are you trying to have group of radio buttons and check all the first one ?

**HTML:**

```
Group1:
<input type="radio" name="group1"/>
<input type="radio" name="group1"/>
<input type="radio" name="group1"/>
<br/>
Group2:
<input type="radio" name="group2"/>
<input type="radio" name="group2"/>
<input type="radio" name="group2"/>
<br/>
Group3:
<input type="radio" name="group3"/>
<input type="radio" name="group3"/>
<input type="radio" name="group3"/>
```

**JQuery:**

```
$('input:radio[name="group1"]').eq(0).attr('checked',true);
$('input:radio[name="group2"]').eq(0).attr('checked',true);
$('input:radio[name="group3"]').eq(0).attr('checked',true);
```

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately these radio button pairs are generated programmatically and I cannot know their number in advance. So I think I cannot use your code.

Comment: @drake035 Does this mean you can't control how many groups they come out in?  Or you just don't know what follows 'gender' in the name?  If you can't control the number of groups, there is nothing you can do to fix it.  If you just can't control the names, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/j7wgm/2/

On Navin HTML use this js:

```
var checked = [];
$('input:radio').each(function(){
    var $el = $(this);
    var name = $el.attr('name');
    if (checked.indexOf(name) === -1){
        checked.push(name);
        $el.prop('checked', true);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As all of your radio buttons have the same name i.e. "gender[]":

```
<input type="radio" name="gender[]" />
```

it means that only one button can be selected. Hence in your scenario you will not be able to "check the first value of each pair".

See the 'input' entry in the [Mozilla documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input) for reference:

**Radio buttons that have the same value for the name attribute are in the same "radio button group"; *only one radio button in a group can be selected at one time*.**

I've created this jsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Fresh/MJsnL/

To demonstrate the problem.

Answer (score 0):

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Bushwazi/fzpyQ/3/)

I took some liberties because the `html` wasn't clearly defined anywhere. Is this anywhere close to your `html`?

HTML using `fieldsets` to break the `radio` buttons apart. I use the `.report` ul just to put the returned values somewhere in my example.

```
<form>
    <legend>I have 3 pairs of radio buttons named "gender[]" in my form. I want to check the first value of each pair using jQuery. I was thinking that this would do the trick:</legend>
    <fieldset>
        <label for="gender[]">Group1:</label>
        <input type="radio" name="gender[]"/>
        <input type="radio" name="gender[]"/>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <label for="gender[]">Group2:</label>
        <input type="radio" name="gender[]"/>
        <input type="radio" name="gender[]"/>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <label for="gender[]">Group3:</label>
        <input type="radio" name="gender[]"/>
        <input type="radio" name="gender[]"/>
    </fieldset>
</form>
<ul class="report">
</ul>
```

JS: used the `fieldsets` to create a `for each loop`, then just checked the first `radio` in there...

```
var $radios = $("input[type=radio]");
var checkInput = function(evt){
    $("form").find("fieldset").each(function(){
        var $this = $(this),
            $firstRadio = $this.find("input[type=radio]").eq(0);
        $( "<li>" + $firstRadio.is(":checked") + "</li>").appendTo(".report");
    });
}
$radios.on("change", checkInput);
```

Comment: And I guess if you don't want to use `fieldsets`, you could use jquery's `:odd` or `:even` selectors...  http://api.jquery.com/even-selector/  http://api.jquery.com/odd-selector/

Answer (score 0):

**What You Have:**

Your problem stems from a misunderstanding about how radio buttons work.  According to the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input), radio buttons are grouped using the name attribute.  You already know that only one radio button per group can be selected.  Since all of your radio buttons have the same group name, you should only be able to select one.  This is the expected behavior as demonstrated by this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zfFkM/).

Your original HTML probably looked like this:

```
<input type="radio" name="gender[]"/>  //:eq(0)
<input type="radio" name="gender[]"/>  //:eq(1)
<input type="radio" name="gender[]"/>  //:eq(2)
<input type="radio" name="gender[]"/>  //:eq(3) This is the one that is finally selected
<input type="radio" name="gender[]"/>
<input type="radio" name="gender[]"/>
```

**What You Need:**

In order to be able to select more than one of these radio buttons, you will need to give each pair a unique name.  Like this:

```
<input type="radio" name="gender1"/>
<input type="radio" name="gender1"/> //First group
<input type="radio" name="gender2"/>
<input type="radio" name="gender2"/> //Second group
<input type="radio" name="gender3"/>
<input type="radio" name="gender3"/> //Third group
```

But now your selector will not work.  You will just need to modify it slightly:

```
jQuery('input[name^="gender"]:eq(1)').attr('checked', 'checked');
```

This code uses the [^= CSS selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/), which finds an attribute that starts with a value.  In this case, it finds all inputs with a name that begins with "gender".  Then you can use the indexing you wanted to before.  Here is the working **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VmM65/8/)**.

One last thing, you may need to review how [:eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) works.  It is 0 based, meaning the first element is element 0, not element 1.  So, to select the first radio button in each pair, you would need number 0, 2, and 4.

Answer (score 0):

Select First Radio Option In Each Groups

```
$("input[type='radio'][value='']").prop("checked", true);
```